# Estrutura para busca e inserção rápida c++

Tags: c++, estrutura-de-dados

Tenho um programa que ele adiciona vários elementos em um vetor. A quantidade está ficando maior que 1000000, preciso adicionar e quando já houver o elemento que estou adicionando, ele retorna a posição de memória.
Está funcionando, mas está ficando muito lento.
Em c++ existe alguma outra estrutura pronta em alguma biblioteca como uma árvore avl?? ou vcs tem alguma outra sugestão para eu resolver esse problema?

Comment: um [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) não serve ? Que tipo de dados são ?

Comment: é um tipo de classe, que guarda um vértice de um grafo

Comment: @Isac, as implementações convencionais implementam `std::map` como uma red-black tree, e não como uma AVL, como descrito pelo OP (mas entendi que foi só uma sugestão).

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Que para o efeito é mais rápido na inserção, pois não tem de fazer tantas rotações. Não obstante, e virando para a questão da velocidade, outra solução seria utilizar um `std::unordered_map` que é implementado como uma *hashtable*

Comment: @LucasVieira Aconselho que você elabore melhor a pergunta, indique o tipo de dados que está armazenando e qual é a solução atual que "Está funcionando, mas está ficando muito lento". Elaborei uma resposta de acordo com uma situação semelhante que encontrei recentemente, espero que já ajude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você diz que:

> preciso adicionar e quando já houver o elemento que estou adicionando, ele retorna a posição de memória.

Existe uma classe com método específico pra isso, que é o `std::set`. O `set` só guarda elementos de valor único (ou seja, sem itens repetidos), e fornece um método para *tentar* adicionar um novo valor, e indicar se foi possível, o `set::insert(...)`

[O seguinte programa](http://cpp.sh/9plty) ilustra esse caso de uso do `set`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

std::set<int> Conjunto; //set de inteiros

void tenta_e_avisa(int v)
{
    auto tenta = Conjunto.insert(v); //insere valor fornecido no conjunto
    if(tenta.second) //o segundo item do retorno indica se número foi criado ou já estava presente
    {
        //o primeiro elemento do retorno de 'insert' contém iterador para o item
        std::cout << "numero " << *tenta.first << " inserido\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "numero " << *tenta.first << " ja existia\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    tenta_e_avisa(1);
    tenta_e_avisa(5);
    tenta_e_avisa(5);
}
```

E produz a saída:

```
numero 1 inserido
numero 5 inserido
numero 5 ja existia
```

Já que você fala de performance, algumas considerações:

- Quando a construção dos objetos é demasiada *cara* para o programa, você pode usar a função `set::emplace(...)`, que constrói condicionalmente o objeto baseado na pré-existência deste ou não.
- O `set` efetivamente armazena os valores em si, assim como o `vector`, e os mantém ordenados, então você precisa fornecer uma maneira de comparar (ordenar, pra ser mais exato), objetos da classe que você está fornecendo, se esta não for um dos tipos básicos.
- Quando a ordem dos itens não for importante, existem classes mais especializadas, como o `unordered_set`. Este, por exemplo, não guarda os itens em si, mas fornece métodos eficientes para verificar se um item de determinado valor já foi adicionado previamente.
- *Tecnicamente*, o `set` tem complexidade de inserção O(log(N)), sendo N o número de elementos já presentes, e o `unordered_set` complexidade média de O(1) (constante, independente do número de elementos já presentes).

[referência para o set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert)

[referência para o set não ordenado](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert)